# UITabBar / UITabBarController Blocking Touches When Scrolled Away

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a custom subclass of `UITabBarController` which adapts a delegate that has a function to shift the tabBar's frame (specifically `frame.origin.y`). When the offset is equal to the height of the screen (that is, it is hidden off-screen) I have a `UIScrollView` extending to the bottom of the screen. Within that `UIScrollView`, I cannot receive touches in the initial frame of the tabBar view.

I have seen recommendations to add intractable subviews to the `UITabBar` or the controller's view. This is far from elegant, and creates a multitude of design issues when working with views that possibly take up the whole screen. I have checked out the little public implementation code of `UITabBarController` and `UITabBar` but nothing I saw there shows how they are blocking those touches.

I'm aware of the recursive nature of hit tests, but short of overriding the hit test and rerouting the touch in the `UITabBarController` subclass, which seems rather unclean, I can't think of a generic way to handle this. This question dives into Apple's `UITabBarController` / `UITabBar` implementation, but I have included some relevant code for clarity:

```
class tab_bar_controller: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate, tab_bar_setter //has included function
{

//.... irrelevant implementation


    func shift(visibility_percent: CGFloat) -> CGFloat //returns origin
    {
            self.tabBar.frame.origin.y = screen_size().height - (visibility_percent * self.tabBar.frame.size.height)
            self.tabBar.userInteractionEnabled = visibility_percent != 0 //no effect
            //self.view.userInteractionEnabled = visibility_percent != 0 //blocks all touches within screen.bounds
            return self.tabBar.frame.origin.y
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not have enough bounty to deny this edit, but it makes the post hardly readable. Please view the initial post:

tl;dr looking for an elegant way to receive touches where uitabbar (from uitabbarcontroller) formerly was (when the tabBar's frame has been [purposefully] adjusted to allow content to use that space).

Comment: I agree it is hardly readable so I tried to revert the edit, but it seems that the original is the same except without code tags? I'm going to break up the sentences a bit and try to improve it...

Comment: There were also changes by the original editor that change the meaning completely; for instance changing the word "interactable" to "intractable", etc. But thank you, I think you have definitely improved the readaibility.